# Imputation of time stamps in R

Tags: r, na, missing-data, imputation

my dataset looks like this (it shows how much time each person takes in going from one place to another, using different cars, taking two stops during the road).

[my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ao3w.png)

I have some NAs on columns "stop time 1" and "stop time 2" and I would like to impute them. Those NAs are not there because people decided to take only 1 or zero stops, but simply because they forgot to record it.

Can you please suggest me how to do this in R? I'm not a data scientist and I'm really new to this. I need to replace those NAs with time stamps (including only hour and minute, e.g. 08:34)

Thanks!!

P.s.: will the algorithm be able to impute on those two columns by taking into account that, since they represent stops between departure and arrival, they have to be comprehended between departure and arrival?

Comment: Please write your questions with a [reproducible example](https://colab.corp.google.com/drive/1Afis4o3ChwSxDauEVSabUxetmmUXl6sh) including what you tried so far and what you expect the output to look like. Imputation here can mean many things, do the breaks have to be evenly spaced? Why are the stops NA, did they just take 1 break?

Comment: Hi Robin, I have not been able to try anything so far (I'm really lost). I have updated the question however :)

Comment: Imputing this is a domain specific question, not a DS one so your PS question should inform the approach taken not vice versa. Otherwise the possibilities are endless (one minute after the previous timestamp, the mid point between the timestamps, if you know the duration of a stop the point that puts the center of the stop duration in the middle of the surrounding two timestamps etc...). You need to know what to fill the data with, the wrong imputation could be irrelevant (in which case it may not even be needed) or disastrous (are the breaks coffee breaks or dropping off heart transplants?)